# how run commands with ssh in shared hosting

Tags: ssh, shared-hosting

I have deployed my Laravel project on shared hosting. My project includes Vite and when I go to this page it returns the error Vite needs to be activated. I added a terminal to my hosting but I can't install or run npm commands, php artisan commands how can I run these commands or how does it work with ssh, I searched for this issue but didn't see anything